# Is it possible to insert a text inside a <v-progress-linear /> (Vue.js / Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to insert a text inside a *v-progress-linear* element (code sample below).

Is that possible ? And if yes, how can it be done ?

```
  <v-progress-linear
    background-color="pink lighten-3"
    color="pink lighten-1"
    value="15"
  >
  </v-progress-linear>
```

Comment: [That component doesn't have a slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress#api), so it's not possible via the provided interface. You could position text over it using css.

Comment: v3 has a default slot https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress-linear/#default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for text inside v-progress-linear is coming in 1.5.

```
<v-progress-linear value="50" height="20" background-color="pink lighten-3" color="pink lighten-1">
  <div>text inside</div>
</v-progress-linear>
```

Here's a pen using the current beta for 1.5 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBNxdW

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry! Just noticed you specifically wanted this for the linear, not the circular. My notes below will handle the circular case. Perhaps ironically, after figuring this out for the circular I ran into the [Vuetify Dialog Loader](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#loader) example which I went with for this project. It does a nice job of presenting text with a linear progress bar as a modal window. That said, leaving my original answer below in case anyone happens to want to add text to the circular version.

Original post: You can achieve this in a roundabout way with something like this. For context, we have the progress element defined at the app level and are toggling its display from child components when we make API calls. The gist of what's happening is there is an app level property for "showWait" which is either empty or contains the text "Please wait...". That property is used for both the v-show and the value of the progress element.

```
<v-progress-circular v-show="showWait" color="accent" size="70" width="7" value="showWait" indeterminate>
   {{ showWait }}
</v-progress-circular>
```

Using a defined "showWait" data property:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
  data: {
    showWait: ''
  },
  methods: {
    ToggleWait() {
      if (this.showWait == '')
        this.showWait = 'Please wait...';
      else
        this.showWait = '';
    }
  }
});
```